# Using resource values as layout attributes (config.xml)

Tags: android

Looking in the android sdk folders, I've found a file called `values/config.xml`.  This seems to be somewhere that you can define values for later use in layouts and animations.

Given the config.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="config_somePadding">50dip</string>
</resources>
```

How would I reference this to use as the layout_height in a layout xml file?

`@string/config_somePadding` is actually the only one I've found that doesn't throw an error in Eclipse (even though there isn't a `config_somePadding` in `values/strings.xml`), but it appears to just put an empty string.

In the sdk, they use an integer for animation duration.  They reference it like this: `android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"`.  Is there a way to use values that aren't integers in the layout_height attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would I reference this to use as
>   the layout_height in a layout xml
>   file?

You wouldn't. Use a [dimension resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html#dimension) instead.

> Is there a way to use values that
>   aren't integers in the layout_height
>   attribute?

You have to use a dimension resource for dimensions.